# Eval exploit detected, able to find the files with grep but can't delete them

Tags: php, wordpress, web-hosting, malware

Unfortunately this night my server has been attacked with eval base64 exploit.

Following and slightly modifying a tutorial I can find the files with:

grep -lr --include=*.php "$c(base64_decode" /path/to/www

However, when I try to delete the files:

grep -lr --include=*.php "$c(base64_decode" /path/to/www | xargs sed -i.bak 's/<?php $c(base64_decode[^;]*;/<?phpn/g'

Nothing happens.

It might be because I had to change the code from eval(base64_decode to $c(base64_decode because that's the way the exploit is coded in my case.

Really looking forward to your input.
This is not the best way to spend the Sunday.

Update:
I've been able to fix it for now.

Looking into ways to hardening my server / wp installations to prevent the next one.. any tips?

Comment: There's no telling what other files may have been attacked. Delete the entire site and restore from your last clean backup.

Comment: Unfortunately that's no option.
Also not only one site is affected but all from 1 reseller account.

Identifying the files goes perfect, I just think there's an error in the removal command

Comment: You're being naive. If you just delete the files you've identified then you'll miss a back door that the attacker has placed elsewhere. You'll be infected again within a week.